# Writing an equivalent LINQ query , on a DbContext, using Reflection, is missing a where condition

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, system.reflection

I can't seem to create an equivalent query in reflection, of a LINQ query.

The goal is to run a query on an Entity Framework DBContext, but specifying the Tablename, and the where clause. There are several tables, so I do not want to copy/paste the same LINQ, for different tables.

The code below works with LINQ, but the reflections equivalent (although I cast it to `System.Linq.IQueryable`), does not allow me to add a `.where` clause.

I included `using System.Linq;` in the class.

Examples I researched from stackoverflow, exposes the Where() clause.

It's probably something minor I am overlooking. (missing a reference?)

```
        // Link to TREESTRUCTURES Database
        var DaContext = new WebApplication7.Models.Db_Entities.TREE_STRUCTURESEntities();
        DaContext.Database.CommandTimeout=300;

        // This works 100% for "HEADCOUNT_NEW"
        var daTreeLeaves = DaContext.HEADCOUNT_NEW
            .Where(x => x.PARENT_COMPONENT == "" && x.COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION == "Headcounts")
            .Select(x => new { x.COMPONENT, x.COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION })
            .OrderBy(x => x.COMPONENT)
            .ToList();

        // Reflections! = This works - Selecting from "HEADCOUNT_NEW" or any other specified available table;
        PropertyInfo dbsetinfo = DaContext.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.ToUpper().Equals("HEADCOUNT_NEW"));

        // I can't seem to get the `.Where()` clause right here (although this code  does return values :) )
        // I omitted the Where here as it would not compile.
        System.Linq.IQueryable anyDbSet = ((IQueryable)dbsetinfo.GetValue(DaContext));

        // Below is my attempt (pseudocode), but the error 
        // "IQueryable does not contain a definition for Where" is returned by VStudio
        System.Linq.IQueryable anyDbSet2 = ((IQueryable)dbsetinfo.GetValue(DaContext)).Where("Id=" + pseudocode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast to `IQueryable<HEADCOUNT_NEW>`

[`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an extension method which works on `IQueryable<T>`, not `IQueryable`.

Comment: Technically it solves the problem.
But, the reason why I use reflection in the first place, is to pass **any** table-name, (all tables have the same structure). 

I can use  `foreach (object entity in anyDbSet)`  to loop through the result-set, then filter on the results, but the initial result-set are BIG. 

Are there different approaches I can consider?

Comment: You could avoid casting and instead use reflection to call `Queryable.Where<T>`.  You could stop fighting the type system and instead use SQL strings, eventually you'd need to call some kind of `FromSql<T>`.  You could use a dynamic LINQ third-party library.

Comment: Just to clarify, If I take the `var result = Queryable.Where((dynamic)anyDbSet, (dynamic) daPredicate);` route, I would need to define my `where clause` (predicate) as a Lambda Expression, with parameters.....  (I am trying to avoid the SQL String approach if possible)